# total visitors at any given instance

Tags: apache, count, analytics

I am working on site analytics and would like to know how I can find the total number of visitors at any given instance. I am concerned only about the current time and not about past views. Right now I am trying to keep the problem simple by not finding the unique visitors.

One approach I can think of is to get total number of http connections at any given instance, assuming that the connection have very short timeout.

My setup includes apache web server and tomcat servlet container.

I know it is still a generic question but this use case is not specific to any particular language.

Answer (score 1):

How about looking in the logs?

For example: 
http://www.geekpad.ca/blog/post/get-unique-visitors-from-apache-log-file